# Use WebSocket with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, websocket

I'm learning AngularJS and I'm attempting to include the WebSocket library https://github.com/PatrickJS/angular-websocket library in my simple app.

My version of AngularJS is :

```
Angular CLI: 11.2.0
Node: 14.15.5
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 11.2.0
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1102.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1102.0
@angular-devkit/core            11.2.0
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.2.0
@schematics/angular             11.2.0
@schematics/update              0.1102.0
rxjs                            6.6.3
typescript                      4.1.5

I'm not using bower for managing packages so to install the websocket library I use : 

npm install angular-websocket --save

which installs successfully.

To use the web socket library I declare a new component : 

import { Component2 } from 'angular-websocket'

@Component2({
    selector: 'courses',
    template: `
        <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let course of courses">
                {{ course }}
                </li>
                </ul>
        `
})
```

but returns an error :

```
Error: src/app/courses.component.ts:5:28 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'angular-websocket'. '/Users/hello-world/node_modules/angular-websocket/dist/angular-websocket.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/angular-websocket` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'angular-websocket';`

5 import { Component2 } from 'angular-websocket'
```

After executing `npm i --save-dev @types/angular-websocket` as suggested by error I receive the following when `executing ng serve` :

```
Error: src/app/courses.component.ts:5:10 - error TS2305: Module '"../../node_modules/@types/angular-websocket"' has no exported member 'Component2'.

5 import { Component2 } from 'angular-websocket'
```

How to import and use the WebSocket library with a component?

Comment: I know this has nothing to do with your question, but why do you learn angularJS and not angular? AngularJS is not maintained anymore, new projects will all use angular. Only old legacy projects will still use angularJS.

Comment: @cloned I'm taking this course: https://www.udemy.com/course/angular-crash-course/ which recommends AngularJS. I didn't realise it's so out of date. Perhaps I should take this instead ? https://www.udemy.com/course/the-complete-guide-to-angular-2/

Comment: It looks like this udemy course is about the current version of angular (there are not *that* many changes between 6 and 11 ... ) So keep taking this course. But the websockets you linked is for AngularJS, which is not compatible to angular project. If I'm not mistaken you can use [websockets in angular](https://tutorialedge.net/typescript/angular/angular-websockets-tutorial/) out of the box with RxJS